# Working with git and remotes

Tags: git, github

Good morning, searched through but didn't find, therefore asking here. :)

I have a situation like the following: `origin` pointing to a project
in github, `fork1` that is pointing to my fork on github and `fork2`
that is pointing to a mate's fork.

Therefore if I do

```
$ git checkout master
# perform various stuff
$ git push
```

all the changes will go to `origin/master` (so far so good).

Now I'd like to take the fork1 master and update it. I did

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout -b fork1-master fork1/master
$ git merge
$ git push
```

I was under the impression that it should push the current changes to
`fork1/master`. Instead it is creating a new branch: `fork1/fork1-master`.

The only way I found for merging in fork1/master is to do

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git checkout -b fork1-master fork1/master
$ git merge
$ git push fork1 fork1-master:master
```

Is it the expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you
Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you

```
git checkout -b fork1-master fork1/master
```

you create a `fork1-master` branch which tracks the `fork1/master` remote branch.

To be able to push in a straightforward way git by default requires (ie in simple mode) that the branch names will be identical. This is desirable in general, but not desirable in your case, because you obviously want to keep the name `master` reserved for `origin/master`.

So you either have to go on and push manually as you do,

```
on fork1-master> git push fork1 HEAD:master
```

Or you will have to tell git to change the default and always push to an upstream branch. This can be done by setting **[push.default](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)** in the configuration to `upstream`.

Here’s how you could do this on the command line instead of the config:

```
on fork1-master> git -c push.default=upstream push
```

it will tell git to identify the branch that you are tracking on the remote and push your branch there.

Comment: worked like a charm and the explanation was brilliant. Thanks a lot.